# Can @PostConstruct be used as a substitute of @Bean/@Produces?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi, postconstruct

I was reading [this post](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2013/01/11/spring-di-and-cdi-comparative-study/) when I thought about the possibility of substituting any `@Bean` (Spring DI) or `@Produces` (CDI) with a simple `@PostConstructor` as in the following CDI example:

Replace:

```
public class MyClassFactory {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public MyClass createMyClass() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.setA(1);
        return myClass;
    }
}

public class MyClass {

    private int a;

    private void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

With:

```
public class MyClass {

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.setA(1);
    }

    private int a;

    private void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Is that correct? What are the differences between those options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `@PostConstruct` defines an interceptor for the *initialization* of a bean. It cannot be used to define the *instantiation* of a bean.

Comment: Oops. My bad. You're right. Sorry for the insane question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see this as an incorrect question.

@PostConstruct method is invoked after the default constructor invocation and dependency injection (if any) are finished. You can initialize instance variables of a bean using the within a @PostConstruct annotated method. In this case, the difference b/w using @PostConstruct and CDI is that, the instance returned by CDI is a contextual one and since it is @RequestScoped, the lifetime of the 'produced' bean is confined to one HTTP request. A new instance of the bean would be produced once the existing HTTP request is complete. In case of @PostConstruct, its an @Dependent scoped bean (by default) and its life cycle would 'depend' upon the bean which injects it (using CDI @Inject)

Comment: Are you telling that the replacement is fine? I asked about the difference between the `@Produces`/`@Bean` approach and the possible `@PostConstruct` approach, not the difference between Spring DI and CDI. Sorry if I wasn't clear.